# INSERT IGNORE don't work on my script

Tags: python, mysql, excel

I have this python script who inserts xcell data into a mysql db, but I need to only inserts rows that aren't duplicates, so I used the INSERT IGNORE sql method also tryed with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, but it doesn't work, it just insert all the data that is in the table. This is the script:

```
import xlrd                                                                                              
import MySQLdb                                                                                           

#Seting the database connection                                                                          
database = MySQLdb.connect (host="localhost", user = "root", passwd = "****", db = "python_insert")      
cursor = database.cursor()                                                                               
query = """INSERT IGNORE INTO test (masina,data_ora,conbustibil) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"""               


#Open and parse the xcell file                                                                           
book = xlrd.open_workbook("asset/testing.xlsx")                                                          
sheet = book.sheet_by_name("Report")                                                                     
for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):                                                                          
    masina = sheet.cell(r, 1).value                                                                      
    data_ora = sheet.cell(r, 0).value                                                                    
    conbustibil = sheet.cell(r, 8).value                                                                 
    values = (masina, data_ora, conbustibil)                                                             
    cursor.execute(query, values)                                                                        


#Closing cursor+database                                                                                 
cursor.close()                                                                                           
database.commit()                                                                                        
database.close()                                                                                         


print "Succes"                                                                                           
columns = str(sheet.ncols)                                                                               
rows = str(sheet.nrows)                                                                                  
print ("Am importat " + columns + " coloane si " + rows + " randuri in MySQL")
```

Comment: To avoid duplicates, you need to define a unique constraint or index.

Comment: How it will look if I chose for example the data_ora to be the constraint ?